# Tornado and PIL: open image from headers

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, tornado

My Tornado app receive the image in headers. So, I want to re-size it and store it. But I have trouble with opening image - to create PIL object I must have the file with image and pass the name of file to open() method of Image module of PIL. But I only have headers and file info there. Should I create temp file to create Image object? Or maybe some other solutions?

```
class ImageHandler(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        f = open("out.jpg", "w")
        im = Image.open(self.request.files["ImageUpload"][0]["body"])
        im.save(f, "JPEG")
        self.finish()
```

TIA!

**UPD1** (@bernie)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-2.2-py2.7.egg/tornado/web.py", line 988, in _execute
    getattr(self, self.request.method.lower())(*args, **kwargs)
  File "server.py", line 160, in post
    im = Image.open(StringIO(self.request.files["ImageUpload"][0]["body"]))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: It may not matter based on your current platform, but you should always use binary modes for binary data. In this case change `w` to `wb`.

Comment: and if I don't use binary write mode - what kind of errors I can face?

Comment: If you are on a platform where the binary flag matters, your image would likely be corrupted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PIL documentation states](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) that we can provide a file name or a file-like object to `open()`.
So we can use [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) to provide PIL a file-like object.
Example applied to your code:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import StringIO

im = Image.open(StringIO(self.request.files["ImageUpload"][0]["body"]))
im.save("out.jpg", "JPEG")
```

Comment: Please ensure you are importing like this: `from StringIO import StringIO`.

Comment: and one more question about StringIO all files from headers will be allocated at memory or on hard drive?

Comment: It is generally recommended to not name any class with the same name as the module because it causes confusion. Nevertheless, existing code which uses such a convention is embedded in a lot of programs and systems so changing it is impractical.

Comment: StringIO creates a file-*like* object. It exists in memory until you write to disk. If you wish to write a file-like object without writing to disk StringIO does that too. Look at `get_value()` in the docs.

Comment: thx a lot! I asked because of I should know where is thin place situated (when there are a lot of request) - in memory or in hardrive